# Why increasing k can increase the sum of squared residuals ? K-means

Tags: residuals, k-means

I defined the distance between each observation and its centroid by:

```
dist=sum((X[,i]-Y[,j])^2)
# X is a 2*n observations matrix, Y is a 2*k centroids matrix
# n is the number of observations
```

Then I created a variable *energy* which represents the sum of *dist* for all observations.

I did that for k varying from 1 to 20 and I got these graphs:
(It is energy vs. k)

[image]
[image]

Why increasing k can increase the sum of squared residuals?

Comment: Your axes are labeled x and y, but you say x and y are the data points and centroids. What do the plots represent; is it energy vs. k? Also, a nice feature of the site is that you can embed images directly into your post by clicking the image button (no need to link to external image hosting sites).

Comment: You are right, it is energy vs k. I edited my post, thank you.

Comment: What you're seeing is most likely the result of suboptimal solutions, as @CarlRynegardh pointed out. Just to add one more point, the true error must decrease monotonically with $k$.

Comment: K-means is a non-deterministic algorithm; it is quite possible for this to occur.  If you run it 20 or 30 times and average the results for each $K$, this effect will typically disappear or at least get much smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that the  plot shows the sum of within distances of k-means. That is the sum of distances of every point to their closest cluster center. The optimization of K-Means does not guarantee a global minimum. You are much more likely to find local minima. As you increase k you might be unlucky and find a bad one. 
You could use a smart initialization strategy like k-means++, or run k-means several times with random initalizations for the cluster centers for each k and pick the solution with lowest within cost.
Using a smart initialization strategy will also speed up the computations and make you converge to the solution faster.

The results of K-Means is dependent on the cluster initialization.